# Is a CSS only container wrapper possible?

Tags: html, css

My goal is to create a content wrapper with each item being of equal height/width. That alone is easy enough and demonstrated below, but I would like the items (DIV's)to wrap to another line if they shrink below the `min-width` so it does not look compressed on mobile displays.

I imagine jQuery could handle this, but for simplicity and size I would like to see if there is a css only solution.

```css
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    
    width:90%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:Gray;
}
#wrapper div {
    display: table-cell;
    height:100px;
    min-width:200px;
}

#one {
    background-color:green
}
#two {
    background-color:blue
}
#three {
    background-color:red
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one">one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one</div>
    <div id="two">two two two two two two</div>
    <div id="three">three</div>
</div>
```

Some details as to the implementation:

This is for a icon grid type landing page, the number of items present are dynamic as is the dimensions of the page. Vertical scrolling due to items wrapping is fine but I do not wish to have any horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Are media queries for lower screen sizes allowed?

Comment: @nevermind That's my backup plan if I cannot get the layout to simply wrap.

Comment: do not use the display:table properties, cells on a row do not wrap, flex does ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `Flexbox` and `flex-wrap: wrap`, here is [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/823/)

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: Gray;
}
#wrapper div {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
#one {
  background-color: green
}
#two {
  background-color: blue
}
#three {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="one">one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one</div>
  <div id="two">two two two two two two</div>
  <div id="three">three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic, I figured flx was the answer, just couldn't get it to work right in my tests!

Comment: Flexbox is the right tool for that, as long as you don't need IE9 and less.

Comment: @enguerranws Ill target IE9< with JS or media queries, flex is definitely the answer for my primarily targeted browsers.

Comment: @Wobbles Alternatively, you can use conditional classes with IE comments to target IE9 and less and apply some CSS fix.

Answer (score 4):

From my comment

> do not use the display:table properties, cells on a row do not wrap, flex does ;)

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: Gray;
}
#wrapper div {
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 200px;
  flex: 1;
}
#one {
  background-color: green
}
#two {
  background-color: blue
}
#three {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="one">one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one</div>
  <div id="two">two two two two two two</div>
  <div id="three">three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also correct, but Nenad beat you to the punch by a few seconds ;-)

Comment: @Wobbles maybe i should not have comment first ;), you got your answer, this is what matters isn't it :)